# Java: Create objects with HashSet

Tags: java

I'm trying to write minigame plugin in Java. In this plugin administrator creates arenas as new objects. My problem is that I need to store players(names as Strings) in HashSet(my personal choose). I searched stack and google for two days and still can't find the right answer. 
Here's part where I got stuck. Presented code is made only to help me figure how to make it. Is there a way to add something to HashSet from for example Arena(1)? Probably I can't do it this way but I really need help with this problem.

Arena class:

```
package test;

import java.util.HashSet;

public class Arena {

    private HashSet<String> online;
    private int id;

    public Arena(int arenaID){
        online = new HashSet<String>();
        this.id = arenaID;
    }

    public HashSet<String> getHashSet(){
        return online;
    }

    public int getArenaId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Arena [online=" + online + ", id=" + id + "]";
    }

}
```

Main class

```
package test;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        HashMap<String, Object> arenas = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        arenas.put("1", new Arena(1));
        arenas.put("2", new Arena(2));

        //arena 1
        System.out.println(arenas.get(1));
        //arena 2
        System.out.println(arenas.get(2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your map contains String keys; you're asking for the values associated with `Integer` keys. Try `get("1")` instead of `get(1)`.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not really clear on what your issue is.

Comment: My issue is that I need somehow to put String values inside HashSet created in object. I don't know if I think correctly but if I create HashSet in arena object then every new arena object have different HashSet or I can't do this that way?

Comment: Clear yourself that do you need a hashset in Arena to store the String object? If you need to store one String object per Arena, then have one String instance variable instead Hashset<String>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I:

I would add another method to `Arena`:

```
public void addToHashSet(String element){
    this.online.add(element);
}
```

and then:

```
((Arena) arenas.get("1")).addToHashSet("something new");
```

or declare

```
HashMap<String, Arena> arenas = new HashMap<String, Arena>();
```

and without casting:

```
arenas.get("1").addToHashSet("something new");
```

Solution II:

Add another method to Arena:

```
public HashSet<String> setHashSet(HashSet<String> hashSet){
        this.online = hashSet;
}
```

and use it:

```
HashSet<String> forOnline = new HashSet<String>();
forOnline.add(something new);

(Arena) arenas.get("1").setHashSet(forOnline);
```